# JASA Express Letters Template

Tags: templates

It may be silly but I wonder if anyone could provide a LaTeX template for JASA Express Letters.

The template for the "regular" journal paper is available on the website of the Acoustical Society of America but I do not seem to be able to find one for the Express Letters.

I hope someone here encountered the problem and has hopefully be more successful than myself in finding the solution.

Comment: Yes, I was told in the future JASA may discontinue submissions to the site using the JASAtex stylesheet. This seems like a step backwards to me. It would be extremely helpful to have an official style file for both the regular and express letter format. JASA gives instructions like: "The length of a JASA-EL paper is restricted to a length of six pages in the final format. (This is approximately equivalent to a four-page article in the Journal of the Acoustical Society of America.) To calculate a rough estimate of the published length of a manuscript is to use the formula, one-half of number of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information is available once you log into the JASA PeerX-Press website: http://jasa.peerx-press.org/html/jasa/Using_LaTeX_for_JASA.html

The JASATeX template you have found is not an official template (despite being available from their website and hosted on their ftp site). Rather they say:

> The ASA greatly prefers that you generate your own LaTeX file as a
>   stand-alone file (one file only) without any use of style files that
>   are not in the standard LaTeX distribution from TUG (TeX User's
>   Group).

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal working example that should do what you want. It isn't exact, but when I tried it with some previously published text the output was basically identical, bar the odd word running onto the next line.

To use, simply paste all the following into a latex file and run. I'd be keen to hear how anybody gets on with this.

```
% Version:  1.0.0  [15/05/13] - Initial build
% Author:   Pete R Jones <petejonze@gmail.com>
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% REQUIRED PACKAGES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % figures
\usepackage{geometry}                       % page layout
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,bm}            % mathematical typesetting
\usepackage{enumitem}                       % nicer enumerated lists
\usepackage{natbib}                         % references
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks=true, 
linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}  % links (esp. for references)
\usepackage{fancyhdr, calc, lastpage}       % headers/footers
\usepackage{booktabs}                       % tables
\usepackage{lipsum}                         % for generating dummy text
\usepackage{endnotes}                       % endotes

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MANUSCRIPT OPTIONS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Uncomment these for 'manuscript' mode (double-line spacing with figures/tables at end)
%\usepackage{endfloat} % for placing figures/tables at end (with marker in appropriate place)       
%\linespread{1.8}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% JASA EXPRESS STYLING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Notes:
%   NO NEED TO EDIT ANY OF THIS!
%   Instructions for authors can be found at: http://scitation.aip.org/journals/doc/ASALIB-home/corp/pdf/jasael/jasaelstyle.pdf
%   The submission guidelines require a copyright notice be placed on the line immediately following the Abstract. However, since this doesn't seem to appear in the published      letter this has been omitted.
%   Headers and footers have not been made to match exactly the published ones (e.g., different for odd/even pages) - though it would be easy to do so. This is in part because the submission guidelines follow a different convention to the published article (somewhat confusingly).
%   Currently no support for footnotes (would be easy enough to add, but these are supposed to be short reports after all)

%% Page-layout commands
\geometry{nohead,right=4.4cm,left=4cm,top=1.65cm,bottom=4cm} %% uses geometry.sty%% 12 pt = 1 pc; 6 pc = 1 in.

% set font (not an exact match to the font used by JASA(?), but a pretty close approximation. Plus bitstream charter is a really nice font)
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{bch}  

% Set headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear existing header
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % remove the line
\fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize USE \textbackslash{}setheader to set running head} %Authors al.: JASA Express Letters}
\fancyhead[C]{\footnotesize page \arabic{page} of \pageref{LastPage}} % [http://dx.doi.org/12.3456/1.2345678]}
\fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize YOUR\_SURNAME, JASA-EL} % Published Online 15 May 2013}
\fancyfoot{} % clear existing footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize \today} % J. Acoust. Soc. Am}           
% extend beyond horizontal margins
\fancyheadoffset[L,R]{\marginparsep+1cm} % requires \usepackage{calc}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{\marginparsep+1cm} % requires \usepackage{calc}
% set vertical spacing
\setlength\headsep{1cm} % rule to body content
\setlength\footskip{1.5cm} % rule to body content

\newcommand\setheader[2]{
    \fancyhead[L]{\footnotesize #1}
    \fancyhead[R]{\footnotesize #2, JASA-EL}
}   

%% Format title/author info
% article title
\renewcommand\title[1]{{\linespread{1} \noindent\LARGE \bf \hskip2.25pc \parbox{.8\textwidth}{%
\LARGE \bf \begin{center} #1 \end{center}\rm } \rm\normalfont\normalsize} }
% author name
\renewcommand\author[1]{{\linespread{1} \noindent\hskip2.25pc \parbox{.8\textwidth}{%
   \normalsize \bf \begin{center} #1 \end{center}\rm } \vskip-1.4pc }}
% address
\newcommand\address[1]{{\linespread{1} \noindent\hskip2.25pc \parbox{.8\textwidth}{%
   \footnotesize \it \begin{center} #1 \end{center}\rm }  \normalsize \vskip-1pc }}
% email
\newcommand\email[1]{\vskip-.3cm \noindent\parskip0pc\hskip2.25pc \footnotesize%
   \parbox{.8\textwidth}{\begin{center}\it #1 \rm \end{center} } \normalsize  \vskip-.2cm}
% PACS codes
\newcommand\PACS[1]{\vskip-2.75pc \begin{center}\parbox{.8\textwidth}{\small\bf PACS numbers: \rm #1 \hfill} \end{center}\vskip4pt}%

%% Abstract
\renewenvironment{abstract}%%
{\vskip1pc\noindent\begin{center} \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth} {\bf Abstract: } }
{ \vspace{.25cm} \end{minipage}\end{center}\normalsize\vskip-1.5pc}%

%% Various customizations
\renewcommand\figurename{Fig.}
\def\fps@table{h}%\def\fps@table{!htb}
\renewcommand\refname{\normalsize References and links \rm}

%% New caption commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@MaxCapWidth{4.25in}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{1pt}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \small
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1. #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\@MaxCapWidth
    \hskip2.25pc\parbox{4.5in}{#1. #2}
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip\normalsize}
\makeatother

%% Formatting of section headers
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@seccntformat[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname.\hspace{.1cm}}
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\renewcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{0pt}%
                                     {-2ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%
                                     {0.65ex plus 1.2ex}%
                                     {\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0pt}%
                                     {-2.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%
                                     {.45ex plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalsize\itshape}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0pt}%
                                     {-2.25ex plus -1ex minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1ex plus .2ex}%
                                     {\small\upshape}}
\makeatother

% Bodytext spacing                                     
\frenchspacing
\setlength\parindent{1.25cm}

% Endnotes
% Set indent to be same as references
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=1cm
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
% Add a vertical gap between endnotes and references
\makeatletter
\let\old@theendnotes\theendnotes
\renewcommand{\theendnotes}{\old@theendnotes\vspace{.3cm}}
\makeatother
% Make footnote alias onto endnote (so can use either command interchangably)  
\let\footnote=\endnote 
% Remove heading
\def\enoteheading{\hspace{.1cm}\vspace{-.25cm}}

% bibliography formatting
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
    % spacing
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
        \footnotesize

        % print endnotes (if any)
        \ifnum\value{endnote} > 0
        \theendnotes % print endnotes
        \fi

      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            %\advance\leftmargin-6pt
            \setlength\itemindent{0pt}% change using the inverse of the length used before
            \setlength\itemsep{-1pt}
            }}
     {\endlist}
     % individual reference formatting
    \newcommand{\enquote}[1]{``#1''}
    \expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
    \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
    \expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
    \providecommand{\bibinfo}[2]{#2}
    \providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{}
    \providecommand{\switchargs}[2]{#2#1}
\makeatother

% Tables
\renewcommand{\toprule}{\specialrule{.35pt}{.3cm}{1pt} \specialrule{.35pt}{1pt}{5pt} } % double rules at top (.3cm vertical gap from caption)
\renewcommand{\bottomrule}{\specialrule{.35pt}{0cm}{1pt} \specialrule{.35pt}{1pt}{0pt} } % and bottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% DOCUMENT BEGINS HERE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

% ================================================================================================
\setheader{Unofficial template}{Jones}

\title{An unofficial template for authors submitting to \textit{JASA-EL}}

\author{Pete R. Jones}
\address{Child Vision Lab, Institute of Ophthalmology, University College London\\11-43 Bath Street, London. EC1V 9EL}
\email{petejonze@gmail.com}


% ================================================================================================
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\PACS{xxxxxx} % replace with appropriate codes (Section 43 Acoustics):  http://www.aip.org/pacs/pacs2010/individuals/pacs2010_regular_edition/reg_acoustics_appendix.htm


% ================================================================================================
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

% ================================================================================================
\section{Methods}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Participants}
\lipsum[1]

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Procedure}
\lipsum[1]

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\subsection{Stimuli}
\lipsum[1]


% ================================================================================================
\section{Results}
Standard \LaTeX{} environments should be used to place tables, figures, and math. An example figure is shown in Fig.~\ref{fig:example}. An example equation is shown in Eq.~\ref{eq:example}. An example table is shown in Table.~\ref{tab:example}. And, just for good measure, here is an example reference to \cite{swets1959multiple}. References can also be made in parentheses \citep[like this;][]{tanner1958masking}. You may want to include additional information in endnotes\endnote{This is an example endnote}. information in endnotes\endnote{This is another example endnote}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h!]
\rule{10cm}{5cm} % e.g., replace with: \includegraphics[width=7cm]{my_figure.png}%
\caption{Sample caption.}
\label{fig:example}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{equation}
H = \frac{1}{2m}(p_x^2 + p_y^2) + \frac{1}{2} M{\Omega}^2
     (x^2 + y^2) + \omega (x p_y - y p_x).
\label{eq:example}
\end{equation}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[h!]
\caption
{
Correlation coefficients, $r$, between A, B, and C.
}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\toprule
&A&B&C\\
\midrule
A&-&0.81&0.82\\
B&0.80&-&0.45\\
C&0.62&0.89&-\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:example}
\end{table}


% ================================================================================================
\section{Discussion}
\lipsum[1]


% ================================================================================================
\section{Conclusions}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,label=(\arabic*)]
\item hello
\item world
\end{enumerate}


% ================================================================================================
\section*{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1]


% ================================================================================================
\begin{thebibliography}{1}      
\bibitem[{Swets (2009)}]{swets1959multiple}
\bibinfo{author}{Swets, J.A.}
  (\textbf{\bibinfo{year}{1959}}). \enquote{\bibinfo{title}{Multiple 
  observations of signals in noise}}, \bibinfo{journal}{J. Acoust. 
  Soc. Am.} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{31}}({\bibinfo{number}{4}}),
  \bibinfo{pages}{514--521}.
\bibitem[{Tanner (2009)}]{tanner1958masking}  
\bibinfo{author}{Tanner Jr., W.P.}
  (\textbf{\bibinfo{year}{1958}}). \enquote{\bibinfo{title}{What 
  is masking?}}, \bibinfo{journal}{J. Acoust. 
  Soc. Am.} \textbf{\bibinfo{volume}{30}}({\bibinfo{number}{10}}),
  \bibinfo{pages}{919--921}.
\end{thebibliography}


% ================================================================================================
\end{document}
```

n.b. Obviously it would be a bit neater if all the formatting code was moved into an external Latex class, but having everything in one file seems to be what JASA prefer.

Comment: Thanks @Pete, I was also looking for a rough template of the EL since it is useful to preview what the article will look like when published, and your template looks pretty accurate to me. It is a shame that JASA has abandoned their support for LaTeX classes.

Answer (score 0):

The Acoustical society now has brand new templates for both articles and express letters, they are very nicely done and well-documented. You can find them at http://acousticalsociety.org/content/latex-package-authors